# Custom Xml Serialization breaks list functionality

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

Ok, so I've got a type:

```
public class MonitorConfiguration 
{

    private string m_sourcePath;
    private string m_targetPath;

    public string TargetPath
    {
        get { return m_targetPath; }
        set { m_targetPath = value; }
    }

    public string SourcePath
    {
        get { return m_sourcePath; }
        set { m_sourcePath = value; }
    }



    //need a parameterless constructor, just for serialization
    private MonitorConfiguration()
    {
    }

    public MonitorConfiguration(string source, string target)
    {
        m_sourcePath = source;
        m_targetPath = target;
    }

}
```

When I serialise and deserialise a list of these, like this

```
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<MonitorConfiguration>));

        using (Stream isfStreamOut = isf.OpenFile("Test1.xml", FileMode.Create))
        {
            xs.Serialize(isfStreamOut, monitoringPaths);
        }
        using (Stream isfStreamIn = isf.OpenFile("Test1.xml", FileMode.Open))
        {
            monitoringPaths = xs.Deserialize(isfStreamIn) as List<MonitorConfiguration>;
        }
```

everything works fine.

However, I really want to hide the public setters of the attributes. This prevents them from being serialised by the XML serialiser. So, I implement my own, like this:

Change the class declaration to this:`public class MonitorConfiguration : IXmlSerializable` 
and add these:

```
    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        //make sure we read everything
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            //find the first element we care about...
            if (reader.Name == "SourcePath")
            {
                m_sourcePath = reader.ReadElementString("SourcePath");
                m_targetPath = reader.ReadElementString("TargetPath");
                // return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteElementString("SourcePath", m_sourcePath);
        writer.WriteElementString("TargetPath", m_targetPath);
    }
```

This seems to work, however, I only ever get the first item from the list out, all the others are forgotten. I've tried with and without the return that's currently commented out. What am I doing wrong here?

It should be noted that this is just a snippet code that illustrates the problem; I'm limited to which XML serialisation technology I'm using my an eternal mechanic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43237/How-to-Implement-IXmlSerializable-Correctly) explains how to get around a few pitfalls when working with IXmlSerializable.

Specifically, you probably need to call `reader.ReadEndElement();` when you've found all your elements in `ReadXml` (see the section *How to Implement ReadXml?* in the article).